# PHP regular expression to parse HTML in a specific way

Tags: php, html, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I have the following HTML:

```
<Text><strong>Cancellation</strong>
A cancellation is free of charge possible until 6PM on arrival day. With later    cancellation or no arrivals without previous cancellation the hotel is justified to place 90% of the booked achievements (excl. breakfast) in calculation whereby the amount at a value of USD 500.00 is not exceeded.
<strong>Check-in time</strong>
Starting from 15:00
<strong>Check-out time</strong>
Until 12:00
<strong>Guarantee</strong>
No guarantee required.</Text>
```

and I want to parse it and store in an array for example like this:

```
array(
 'Cancelation'    => 'A cancellation is free of charge possible until 6PM on arrival day. With later    cancellation or no arrivals without previous cancellation the hotel is justified to place 90% of the booked achievements (excl. breakfast) in calculation whereby the amount at a value of USD 500.00 is not exceeded.',
 'Check-in time'  => 'Starting from 15:00',
 'Check-out time' => 'Until 12:00',
 'Guarantee'      => 'No guarantee required.'
);
```

Thank you for the hints in advance.

Comment: well, give us a hint of what you tried and then we'll hint a fix why it's not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Simple HTML DOM http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://techgossipz.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-parse-html-using-dom-with-php.html) tutorial, no need to use hungry regex engine.

Comment: I'm trying to load the XML in a Dom object but after that I'm not able to parse the content of all <strong> tags and the text between them.

Comment: @user1755641 Make your HTML/XML valid. Then, parse all the `strong` tags, and the text in between...

Comment: Agreed with @Hidde, if your HTML is generated dynamically, then consider to rework it`s generation procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Add the **valid** HTML into a `DOMElement` object. With it you can select children and extract their HTML/text into variables.

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php

Comment: That only works with valid html. Which this clearly isn't.

Comment: Well, the input html is still invalid. So your solution won't work.

Comment: I am offering a solution for the situation where he structures the data like he should. Then, this will work, and is a lot nicer than REGEX parsing.

Comment: I am saying he needs to EDIT his HTML/XML, which he should anyway, and then solve his problem!

Comment: I'm not able to edit the xml/html I receive it in this way from another system.

Comment: Chill dude. No one is criticising you.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I think too many people are whining about the invalid HTML/XML, which is not my problem.