# Using Simple HTML DOM to get specific plain text

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

**Problem:**

Trying to extract specific text from HTML code that is available to me through PHP.

**HTML code:**

```
<a href="/debatt/s-vill-ha-tioarig-skolplikt-och-farre-elever-i-klassen">
    <span class="number">2. </span>Skolplikt och färre elever i klassen
    <br />
    <span class="metadata">I går</span>
</a>

<a href="/sthlm/edholm-backar-om-skolornas-smorforbud">
    <span class="number">3. </span>Edholm backar om skolornas smörförbud
    <br />
    <span class="metadata">16 okt</span>
</a>
```

**Desired output:**

```
2. Skolplikt och färre elever i klassen
3. Edholm backar om skolornas smörförbud
```

Both code examples have the same HTML structure. Is it possible through Simple HTML DOM to do this or should regular expressions be pursued?

Comment: Simple HTML DOm can do this, you can find readymade class (simplehtmldom) in the net to parse HTML and get desired texts from the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to frequently do this, you can use a very handy and easy class for parsing html dom.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Add the HTML into a `DOMElement` object. With it you can select children and extract their HTML/text into variables.

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php

---

*Same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950525/711129*